# block request in javascript before calling the controller action in asp.net mvc app

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developping an asp.net mvc application where I have an href on my page which when clicked one, calls a method of my mvc controller :

```
<a href="/MyProject/Controller/Action" data-stateful="false">Send</a>
```

I would like to stop this request to be done when a condition is not valid.
But my js verification doesn't work :

```
if (!isValid())
{
    window.stop();
}
```

I would like to know how to stop the request to be done.

Comment: Can you show how you're attaching the event handler? All you should need is `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

you can return false onclick event ( attach the event in your regular way, jquery, angularjs, etc...)

```
<a href="/MyProject/Controller/Action" onclick='return isValid' data-stateful="false">Send</a>
```